# Setup SSL with HTTP(s) load balancer on google compute engine

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing

I'm working on a project on Google Compute Engine in which I have installed `Jira Service Desk of Atlassian` on the VM based on `Ubuntu 16.04` and I have an SSL certificate which I want to install on that VM, I figured it out that I can install my own certificate using `Load Balancer` but don't know how to do this?

How can I install my `SSL Certificate` with an `HTTPS Load Balancer` on a compute engine VM with Jira Service Desk of Atlassian installed?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a HTTPS Load Balancer if you just want to install your SSL certificate.

To install your SSL certificate in Jira see their documentation [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/integrating-jira-with-apache-using-ssl-861253896.html)

However if you actually want to use a load balancer then you must associate at least one SSL certificate with the load balancer's target proxy, it could be Google-managged or self-managed. Detailed steps in [GCP public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates).